# asserting against thrown error objects in jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I have a function which throws an object, how can I assert that the correct object is thrown in jest?

```
it('should throw', () => {

  const errorObj = {
    myError: {
      name: 'myError',
      desc: 'myDescription'
    }
  };

  const fn = () => {
    throw errorObj;
  }

  expect(() => fn()).toThrowError(errorObj);
});
```

https://repl.it/repls/FrayedViolentBoa

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you are looking to test the contents of a custom error (which I think is what you are trying to do). You could catch the error then perform an assertion afterwards.

```
it('should throw', () => {
 let thrownError;

 try {
   fn();
 }
 catch(error) {
  thrownError = error;
 }

 expect(thrownError).toEqual(expectedErrorObj);
});
```

As Dez has suggested the toThrowError function will not work if you do not throw an instance of a javascript Error object. However, you could create your custom error by decorating an instance of an error object.

e.g.

```
let myError = new Error('some message');
myError.data = { name: 'myError',
                 desc: 'myDescription' };
throw myError;
```

Then once you had caught the error in your test you could test the custom contents of the error.

```
expect(thrownError.data).toEqual({ name: 'myError',
                                   desc: 'myDescription' });
```

Comment: yeah the try catch will work, it feels a bit long winded having to introduce a variable, but if this is currently the only way... nice one

Comment: I'd also ensure to add an expert.assertions(1) as well after incase the function doesn't error and prevent jest passing.

Answer (score 6):

You need to throw a Javascript `Error` object, so the Jest `toThrowError` method identifies that an error has been thrown. Also the `toThrowError` looks to match the message of the error thrown or if an error has been thrown if you just check by `.toThrowError()`.

```
it('should throw', () => {
  
  const errorObj = {
    myError: {
      name: 'myError',
      desc: 'myDescription'
    }
  };
  
  const fn = () => {
    throw new Error(errorObj.myError.desc);
  }
  
  expect(() => fn()).toThrowError("myDescription");
});
```

Comment: I am unable to alter the source unfortunately, (as this was perfectly testable with mocha, chia and sinon). If im asserting on an Error object, it doesnt matter what object I pass to the Error object, it will still pass which isnt really what I want, e.g. expect(() => fn()).toThrowError(new Error({}));

Comment: this is not gonna work soundly, if you want to check a "complete match", since toThrow/toThrowError only ever checks the the .message property of the thrown object.

Comment: In the second case, in which i want to pass the entire object; new Error(errorObj) is returning a typescropt error "not assignable to type string".

Comment: @DoniaElFouly yes, because it only takes a string the first argument and it would convert the object to [object Object]. Missed the serialization. Anyway I am going to delete it as it doesn't provide any useful case because it doesn't use JavaScript error properly.

Answer (score 5):

It's known issue in jest, see https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/8140

Meanwhile, here is my workaround - https://github.com/DanielHreben/jest-matcher-specific-error

Comment: Pretty awesome. Good job. Hopefully that matcher can be added into Jest in the future.

Answer (score 4):

If the objective is to check partial content of error, we can use Jest [expect.objectContaining](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectobjectcontainingobject) to help us keep code simple and check object payload returned as error :

```
const invalidJob = () => {
  throw {
    type: '/errors/invalid-job',
    message: 'This job is invalid',
  };
};
```

```
expect(() => invalidJob()).toThrowError(
  expect.objectContaining({
    type: '/errors/invalid-job',
  })
);
```

Also possible with nested objects :

```
const invalidJob = () => {
  throw {
    response: {
      type: '/errors/invalid-job',
      message: 'This job is invalid',
    },
    status: 400
  };
};
```

```
expect(() => invalidJob()).toThrowError(
  expect.objectContaining({
    status: 400,
    response: expect.objectContaining({
      type: '/errors/invalid-job'
    })
  })
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add a custom matcher.

## 1. Custom Matcher

```
import { CsrfError } from '../src/shield';

declare global {
  namespace jest {
    interface Matchers<R> {
      toThrowCsrfError(expected: {
        statusCode: number;
        message: string;
      }): CustomMatcherResult;
    }
  }
}

const mismatchResult = (message: string) => ({
  pass: false,
  message: () => message,
});

expect.extend({
  toThrowCsrfError(received, expected): jest.CustomMatcherResult {
    try {
      received();
    } catch (error) {
      const isCsrfError = error instanceof CsrfError;
      if (!isCsrfError) {
        return mismatchResult('Not an CsrfError Error');
      }

      if (error.message !== expected.message) {
        return mismatchResult(
          `Recieved Message "${error.message}" different from expected "${expected.message}"`
        );
      }

      if (error.statusCode !== expected.statusCode) {
        return mismatchResult(
          `Recieved statusCode "${error.statusCode}" different from expected "${expected.statusCode}"`
        );
      }

      return {
        pass: true,
        message: () => ``,
      };
    }

    return {
      pass: false,
      message: () => `Expected to throw, but didn't`,
    };
  },
});
```

## 2. Add to setupFilesAfterEnv

In your `jest.config` add the file above to your `setupFilesAfterEnv` list, for example:

```js
const config = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./test/matchers.ts'],
};

module.exports = config;
```

## 3. Call

```
  expect(() => {
    shield({ pathname: 'https://example.com/' });
  }).toThrowCsrfError({ statusCode: 401, message: 'No CSRF cookie.' });
```

Answer (score 0):

When I need to test a custom error (subclass of Error), I use the following approach:

```js
export class CustomError extends Error {
  constructor(public code: string, public data: any) {
    super(`Custom Error`);
  }
}

export async function method(): Promise<void> {
  throw new CustomError('ABC001', { field: 'X' });
}

// test:

it('should throw a CustomError for field X', () => {
  expect.assertions(1); // Expects for an error
  return method().catch(e => {
    expect(Object.assign({}, e)).toStrictEqual({
      code: 'ABC001',
      data: { field: 'X' }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you **shouldn't** throw an object or anything but the **Error object itself** ([eslint recommendation](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-throw-literal/)).

- If throwing an error with a message is enough for you, you can do:

```
it('should throw', () => {
  function fn() {
      throw new Error('Function not implemented.');
  }
  // Expect fn to throw an error with message
  expect(fn).toThrow('Function not implemented.');
});
```

- If you need to pass more information along this error, you need to create a custom error:

```
class CustomError extends Error {
    public statusCode: number;

    constructor(
        message: string,
        { statusCode }: { statusCode: number }
    ) {
        super(message);
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }
}

it('should throw a custom Error', () => {
  function fn() {
      throw new CustomError('Function not implemented.', { statusCode: 500 });
  }
  // Expect fn to throw an error with message and props
  expect(fn).toThrowCustomError(new CustomError('Function not implemented.', { statusCode: 500 }));
});
```

With `toThrowCustomError` a custom matcher

```
// jest.d.ts
declare namespace jest {
    interface Matchers<R> {
        toThrowCustomError(error: CustomError): CustomMatcherResult;
    }
}

// jest.setup.ts
expect.extend({
    toThrowCustomError(fn: () => void, error: CustomError) {
        try {
            fn();
        } catch (err) {
            if (err.statusCode !== error.statusCode) {
                return {
                    message: () => this.utils.printDiffOrStringify(error.statusCode, err.statusCode, "Expected statusCode", "Received statusCode", true),
                    pass: false
                };
            }
            return {
                message: () => "expected to throw a CustomError",
                pass: true
            };
        }
        return {
            message: () => "expected to throw a CustomError but nothing was thrown",
            pass: false
        };
    }
});
```

- If your function is asynchronous, you can do:

```
it('should throw', async () => {
  async function fn() {
      await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
      throw new CustomError('Function not implemented.', { statusCode: 500 });
  }
  // Expect fn to reject and throw an error with message and props
  await expect(fn).rejects.toThrowCustomError(new CustomError('Function not implemented.', { statusCode: 500 }));
});
```

With `toThrowCustomError` slightly different

```
// jest.d.ts
declare namespace jest {
    interface Matchers<R> {
        toThrowCustomError(error: CustomError): Promise<CustomMatcherResult>;
    }
}

// jest.setup.ts
expect.extend({
    toThrowCustomError(err: any, error: CustomError) {
      if (err.statusCode !== error.statusCode) {
          return {
              message: () => this.utils.printDiffOrStringify(error.statusCode, err.statusCode, "Expected statusCode", "Received statusCode", true),
              pass: false
          };
      }
      return {
          message: () => "expected to throw a CustomError",
          pass: true
      };
    }
});
```

Output in case of an error:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I would like to propose a workaround that uses the `rejects` object in Jest.
Assuming that `fn` is a syncronous function you can write your a test like this:

```js
it('should throw', async () => {
  const errorObj = {
    myError: {
      name: 'myError',
      desc: 'myDescription'
    }
  };

  const fn = () => {
    throw errorObj;
  }

  await expect(async () => fn()).rejects.toMatchObject(errorObj);
});
```

With these solution you make the fn() execution asyncronous. This allow us to use the `rejects` object that will contain the object of the thrown exception. With that you can use the `toMatchObject()` to check the shape of the object thrown.