# JEST: Ignore tabs/spaces in expected error object

Tags: jestjs

In my test I know exactly what the output is I'm asserting on. However, I have an issue with the output.

It seems to not handle the whitespace differences while the objects are similar.

The assertion outputs the following code:

```
    Expected: [Error: Expected path "my_path[0].grandparent.parent" to be found in:
              [
                {
                  "name": "ValidationError",
                  "path": "my_path[0].grandparent.parent.child",
                  "type": "required",
                  "errors": [
                        "error in path two"
                  ],
                  "inner": [],
                  "message": "error in path two",
                  "params": {
                        "path": "my_path[0].grandparent.parent.child"
                  }
                }
              ]]
    Received: [Error: Expected path "my_path[0].grandparent.parent" to be found in:·
     [
        {
            "name": "ValidationError",
            "path": "my_path[0].grandparent.parent.child",
            "type": "required",
            "errors": [
                "error in path two"
            ],
            "inner": [],
            "message": "error in path two",
            "params": {
                "path": "my_path[0].grandparent.parent.child"
            }
        }
    ]]
```

In the test I'm using the "[toEqual](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/22.x/expect#toequalvalue)" matcher

```
const expectedError = new Error(`Expected path "my_path[0].grandparent.parent" to be found in:
          [
            {
              "name": "ValidationError",
              "path": "my_path[0].grandparent.parent.child",
              "type": "required",
              "errors": [
                    "error in path two"
              ],
              "inner": [],
              "message": "error in path two",
              "params": {
                    "path": "my_path[0].grandparent.parent.child"
              }
            }
          ]`);

it('foobar', () => {
  try {
    // custom expect method which throws an error in this case
    expect({
      my_path: [{ grandparent: { parent: undefined } }],
    }).toBeInvalidWith(schema, required, 'my_path[0].grandparent.parent');
  } catch (error) {
    expect(error).toEqual(expectedError);
  }
});
```

Comment: Never check an exception for equality. Some properties of the exception object should have relevant values but the message must be free to change. A specific error message is usually not a business requirement. The best way to use exceptions (and to write expectations about them) is to create one specific exception type for each exceptional situation. Then in the use case you can check the type of the caught exception and some of its properties (`path`, `type`) but never the error message.

Comment: The posted use case is confusing. Does it describe a normal processing flow or a situation when the code throws an exception? They should not be mixed and an use case should not contain `try/catch`, `if`s or loops.

Comment: @axiac That makes sense. Was inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48707111/asserting-against-thrown-error-objects-in-jest. But you're right, the error itself is not important. I do however like to check for the path to be reflected in the error message. The answer from estus-flask works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with `try..catch` is that it may result in false positives, this should be additionally handled.

Since it's `my_path[0].grandparent.parent` part that is relevant, the error can be caught and matched:

```
  try { 
    ...
    throw new Error('Should not be evaluated');
  } catch (error) {
    expect(error.message).toEqual(
      expect.stringContaining('Expected path "my_path[0].grandparent.parent" to be found in:')
    );
  }
```

This is a case for advanced matcher, like jest-extended [toThrowWithMessage](https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended#tothrowwithmessagetype-message).

Comment: Note: Updated the answer with stringContaining inside toEqual.

Comment: @Remi `expect(error.message).toEqual(expect.stringContaining(...))` -- why so complicated? `expect(error.message).toContain(...)`. But again, do not check the error message, check the relevant properties (`path`, `type`, `params` etc).

Comment: Oké. But the error does not have `path`, `type` etc, in the catch. How should I extract those?